# Nhibernate mapping generator

Tags: nhibernate

I was wondering if there is a tool to generate Nhibernate mapping and class automatically from the database, kinda what subsonic does? Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41752/nhibernate-generators http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578341/what-is-the-best-code-generator-for-nhibernate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[NHibernate Mapping Generator](http://nmg.codeplex.com/)

> Project Description
>
> A simple utility to generate
>   NHibernate mapping files and
>   corresponding domain classes from
>   existing DB tables.

[Screenshot http://i3.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=nmg&DownloadId=57926](http://i3.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=nmg&DownloadId=57926)

It's in beta, I've not tried this though :)

Answer (score 2):

In case its still relevant - have a look at the [Mindscape NHibernate Designer](http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/nhdesigner) if you are interested in a Visual Studio integrated option.

[image]
[Some more screenshots are here](http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/nhdesigner/getting-started)

Its probably the closest to what you would get with Subsonic, and it covers most of the commercial databases out there for the drag/drop and 2 way round tripping, so its pretty easy to cover off most modelling concerns.

Note: I am one of the founders of Mindscape, so have a clear bias towards the product :)

Answer (score 1):

There a new 2.0 Beta 2 release available with lots of new features and support for fluent nhibernate, one-to-many and many-to-many mapping.

http://www.codeplex.com/Wikipage?ProjectName=nmg